# Good day! In this program, I make the menu for restaurant including Handle function.I can't connect array: Name, Price with functions getall and get

Tags: go

Good day! In this program, I make the menu for restaurant including Handle function.

**Problem Statement**:
I can't connect array: `Name, Price` with functions `getall` and `get`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "strconv"
    "net/url"
)

type Menu struct {
    Name string
    Price  int
    description string
}

func  (m Menu) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", m.Name, m.Price, )
}

func main() {
    x :=[]Menu{
        {Name:"Crispy", Price:31},
        {Name:"Burger", Price:42},
        {Name:"Superstar",Price:17},
        /*{"Cola", 26},
        {Name:"Superstar", Price:40},
        {Name:"Nuggets", Price:19},*/
    }
    //getall(&x)
    fmt.Println(x)

    http.HandleFunc("/getall", getall)
    http.HandleFunc("/get", get)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func getall(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for _,num := range []Menu{}{
        io.WriteString(w, "<p>"+m.Name+" Price "+strconv.Itoa(num)+"</p>")
    }
}

func get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url := url.URL{}
    println(url.String())
    attr := r.URL.Query()
    fmt.Println(attr)
    id := attr["id"][0]
    fmt.Println("id of request " + id)
    v := id
    d:= []Menu{}
    if a, err := strconv.Atoi(v);
    err == nil {
        io.WriteString(w, "<p> "+Name[a-1]+" price "+strconv.Itoa(d[a-1])+"</p>")
    }
}
```

Help me to implement array in `getall` and `get` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to help you as it seems you are genuinely trying to learn go. I've made few changes in your code. I've moved the menu listing in each handler. You may keep it global. Find the changed code below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strconv"
)

type Menu struct {
    Name        string
    Price       int
    description string
}

func (m Menu) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", m.Name, m.Price)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)

    http.HandleFunc("/getall", getall)
    http.HandleFunc("/get", get)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func getall(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    x := []Menu{
        {Name: "Crispy", Price: 31},
        {Name: "Burger", Price: 42},
        {Name: "Superstar", Price: 17},
    }

    for _, m := range x {

        io.WriteString(w, "<p>"+m.Name+" Price "+strconv.Itoa(m.Price)+"</p>")
    }

}

func get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    x := []Menu{
        {Name: "Crispy", Price: 31},
        {Name: "Burger", Price: 42},
        {Name: "Superstar", Price: 17},
    }

    url := url.URL{}
    println(url.String())
    attr := r.URL.Query()
    fmt.Println(attr)
    id := attr["id"][0]
    fmt.Println("id of request " + id)
    v := id
    if a, err := strconv.Atoi(v); err == nil {
        io.WriteString(w, "<p> "+x[a-1].Name+" price "+strconv.Itoa(x[a-1].Price)+"</p>")
    }

}
```

Try visiting: http://localhost:8080/getall OR http://localhost:8080/get?id=1

Comment: Thank you a lot for help, but I still wanted to have Menu in main function, and then work with it in other functions. Still do not understand how to do it. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

user `for m :=range menu{...}`to implement getall(), use `for i,_ := range menu{ if i == espect {...}}` to implement get()